# Unable to find connection string

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF library project that is using the connection string referenced in WCF console app which is used as a host. Connection string is in App.Config file.
But when I run a project I get an error in the library that it is unable to find connection string. I'm new to WCF so I'm not really sure how WCF host works.
Do you have any suggestions on how to make it work?

This is the line of code in library that gets the error:

```
using (OrganizationService service = new 
OrganizationService("MyConnectionString"))
```

And this is the console app that is used to host a service:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ServiceHost selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1));

    try
    {
        selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), new 
            WSHttpBinding(), "Service1");

        ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
        smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
        selfHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

        selfHost.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("The service is ready.");

        Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to terminate the service.");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadLine();
        selfHost.Close();
    }
    catch (CommunicationException ce)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("An exception occurred: {0}", ce.Message);
        selfHost.Abort();
    }
}
```

app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<startup> 
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1" />
</startup>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="
Server=https://crmtest.com:444;
Username=user;Password=pass"/>
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

connection works when i try it with my other app

Comment: When i run the client(webapp) i see that service has started, but the library cannot find connection string

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure why are you adding  Service1.  in your connection string name  you just need to add the exact connection string name  in app config

so it should just be

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="
Server=https://crmtest.com:444;Initial Catalog="YourDatabaseName";
Username=user;Password=pass"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: I used it just like that and got the same error, so i tried something different

Comment: @NadanMarenković  I noticed  that you haven't given any database name in your connection string  .Which database you are trying to connect ?   Did you tried connecting your  to you database using Sql Management Studio using the these credentials ?

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be something wrong with the configuration file.  Ordinarily, when we use WCF library project to create the WCF service, we should move our configuration code into the configuration file recognized by your hosting environment. Namely, the Appconfig file of the library project does not take effects, we should copy the System.servicemodel section to the actual project.
Please refer to the below link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/deploying-a-wcf-library-project
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: Yes, i guess there is something wrong with app.config in service and a host

Comment: If you have any new progress, please let me know. feel free to let me knwo if the problem still exists.